# How to end whileTrue loop when same input value is put in twice?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm sorry if it looks weird, it's my first time posting.

The question is how do I end the loop and print the whole story if the same word str input is put twice in a row (I tried to do that with the len(set()) but it didn't work)?

```py
story = ""

while True:
    word = input("Give me a word: ")

    if word == "end" or word == len(set(word)):
        break

    story += word + " " 

print(story)
```

Comment: I know that one tries desperate things if one struggles to find a solution, but ask yourself: How could the string `word` ever be the same as the number given back from `len`?

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For twice in a row, I would just keep track of the previous word

```
story = ""
prev = ""

while True:

    word = input("Give me a word: ")

    if word == "end" or word == prev:

        break

    prev = word
    story += word + " "

print(story)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
story = []
prev = ""

while True:

    word = input("Give me a word: ")

    if word == "end" or word == prev:

        break

    prev = word
    story.append(word+" ")

print(''.join(story))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''Program to take single word as input from users, 
combine input word as a string and end the program
if any of the word in the string is repeated'''
import re
storyString = ""

def takeInput(storyString):
    global inputWord 
    inputWord = input("Give me a word: ")
    creatWordFromString(storyString)

def creatWordFromString(storyString):
    storyList = storyString.split()
    if inputWord in storyList:
        exit()
    else:
        storyList.append(inputWord)
        storyString =' '.join(storyList)
        print(storyString)
        takeInput(storyString)
    
takeInput(storyString)
```